# Playing audio object when state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I trigger playing audio correctly on constant state change in React?:

```js
const [previousItem, setPreviousItem] = useState()

useEffect(() => {
  if (myArray ? .size > 0) {
    const item = Array.from(myArray.values()).pop()
    if (
      item &&
      !item.isChecked
    ) {
      const audio = new Audio(blipSound)
      audio.play()
      setPreviousItem(item)
    }
  }
}, [myArray, previousItem ? .id])
```

Sometimes I get sound (it's just a beeping sound) if though `console.log` was not hit i.e. didn't really go inside the `if` condition. I also get `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first` even though it beeps.

TIA!

Tried that code, tried putting audio outside of useEffect.